# Tick method crashing after game launch

Tags: java, eclipse

The idea is that there is a timer of 2000 ticks (2s) and every time it reaches a multiple of 2000 (eg. 2, 4, 6, 8), it will spawn an entity for the enemy in my game. That entity is a bullet. I put a dropbox of the rest of my code because it will get confusing.  I'm using Java Eclipse IDE to code my game. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kuvoxzjf00wa8jf/AAD-MaXXcnHMn4PtW-X_vHcUa?dl=0

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Game.src.main.Game.tick(Game.java:150)
    at com.Game.src.main.Game.run(Game.java:126)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This error occurs after the game has launched and when the button 'play'is clicked. And this is where the error is occurring. Line 126: tick() in public void run() and Line 150: e.tick(). I put at the top of the code `private Enemy e`; to track where the enemy is so that the Enemy Bullet can fire.

```
public void run(){ //Game Loop - Heart of Game 
            init();
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime(); // Long is the same as an int just stores a higher pos number and a lower neg number
            final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
            double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
            double delta = 0; //calculates time past to catch up; the number will increase
            //^ Will only get ran once 
            int updates = 0;
            int frames = 0;
            long timer = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Milliseconds
            while(running){
                long now = System.nanoTime(); //takes time to get from long lastTime to this line
                delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
                lastTime = now;
                if(delta >= 1){
                    try {
                        tick();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    updates++;
                    delta--;
                }
                render();
                frames++;

                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                    timer += 1000;
                    System.out.println(updates + "Ticks, Fps " + frames);
                    updates = 0;
                    frames = 0;
                }
            }
            stop();

         }
         private void tick() throws InterruptedException{ //everything that updates
            if(State == STATE.GAME) {

            e.tick();
            p.tick();
            c.tick();

            Instant start = Instant.now();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            Instant end = Instant.now();

            Duration elapsed = Duration.between(start, end);

            if(elapsed.toMillis() >= 2000) {
                c.addEntity(new EnemyBullet(e.getX(), e.getY(), tex, this));
            }
            }

            if(enemy_killed >= enemy_count) {
                enemy_count = 5;
                enemy_killed = 0;
                c.createEnemy(enemy_count);
            }

         }
```

Comment: EVERY `tick` you're creating a new `Timer` ... this won't scale well, but your key problem is, you're not actually starting the `Timer`.  It's not `Enemy`s responsibility to perform this functionality anyway.  Instead, in you "main-loop"/engine, you need to keep track of how long since a enemy was spawned, after 2 seconds, you run your logic to determine what should be done, this is not a job for a Swing `Timer` (at least not based on the available code).  So you question now becomes "how to determine the duration between two points in time" which was been answered a million times

Comment: ok I'll have a look

Comment: I added timer.start(); after I created the timer and now getting a syntax error.

Comment: First, no, stop, do not use `Timer` this way!  You will create and start a new timer every time `tick` is called, which could possibly 60 times a second, this will NOT scale well.  You need a new/better solution.

Comment: ah ok gotcha I think I'm onto another method

Comment: I found something but just to be sure would timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() work inside my main game loop/engine

Comment: Technically, yes, but now you're introducing another thread into your code, which could cause synchronisation issues (race conditions, deadlocks, dirty read/writes).  You should be using the existing "main-loop" which is already updating the state of your game scheduling paint updates on a regular interval.  Inside this, you need to make determinations about how long since the last spawn was and if a new spawn needs to take place. Java has a powerful date/time API built in now - so I'd recommend having a look at the `Duration` and `Instant` classes

Comment: I added more code to the original post about the error I am getting. My understanding of it is that maybe more than one operation is being used but I do not see that with mine.

Comment: You need to convert the `Duration` to a meaningful value, probably `elapsed.toMillis()`

Comment: So would I do that when I call the if statement or do I redefine in this line Duration elapsed = Duration.between(start, end);

Comment: Yes, you need to calculate the difference between now and when you started, then convert the value to a meaningful comparable value

Comment: Sorry, there is a time gap between each message been stuck doing other subjects. I seemed to have managed to make it into an if statement (code: if(elapsed.toMillis() >= 2000) {} ) now inside that bracket I want to spawn the bullet. Assuming that if statement is correct how would I make it spawn when the enemy moves. For the player, I made it get the position of the player then spawn there but I wasn't sure how you would do it for the enemy.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ^

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please read the comment about the time gap, it is an update to what I have done